# How to get reference table fields with django model query

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-orm

When I am trying to fetch foreign key table using django model I am only unable to get the referenced table details.

I have two models TblVersion and TblProject defined below

```
class TblVersion(models.Model):
    version_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    project = models.ForeignKey(TblProject, models.DO_NOTHING)
    version_major = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    version_minor = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tbl_version'


class TblProject(models.Model):
    project_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tbl_project'
```

My current code implementation:

```
        result= TblVersion.objects.all().select_related()
        data = serializers.serialize('json', result)
        print(data)
```

```
Code Result:
[
  {
    "model": "CCM_API.tblversion",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": { "project": 1, "version_major": 1000, "version_minor": 0 }
  },
  {
    "model": "CCM_API.tblversion",
    "pk": 2,
    "fields": { "project": 2, "version_major": 1000, "version_minor": 0 }
  },
  {
    "model": "CCM_API.tblversion",
    "pk": 3,
    "fields": { "project": 2, "version_major": 1000, "version_minor": 2 }
  }
]


The code output lacks the foreign key fields (Project Name). I want a list of version numbers with their respective projects like this.

| Version Id | Major Version | Minor Version | Project Id | Project Name|
| -------- | -------- |-------- |-------- |-------- |
| 1   | 1000   |1 | 1| PROJ_1 |
| 2   | 1000   |1 | 2| PROJ_2 |
| 3   | 1000   |2 | 1| PROJ_1 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the current implementation of my code that solved the problem.

```
projects = []
result = TblVersion.objects.all()    
for ver in result:
    versions.append({
        'id':ver.version_id,
        'major_version':ver.version_major,
        'minor_version':ver.version_minor,
        'project_name':ver.project.project_id,
        'project_name':ver.project.project_name,
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

select_related method accepts an arg of fields that relates to an other model

`result= TblVersion.objects.all().select_related("product")`

**Update**

To add those related field to be serializable u can list the values as

`result = TblVersion.objects.all().select_related("product").values("id", "version_id", ..., "product__id", "product__name")`

Comment: I am still not not getting the project name after serialization

Answer (score 0):

You can use serializers to view the referenced table fields.

#models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    seller=models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    pname=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description=models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
    price=models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.pname
    
class Order(models.Model):
    buyer=models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity=models.IntegerField()
    totalprice=models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.product.pname
```

#serializers.py

```
class OrderSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    pname=serializers.CharField(source="product.pname",read_only=True)
    category=serializers.CharField(source="product.category",read_only=True)
    description=serializers.CharField(source="product.description",read_only=True)
    pprice=serializers.CharField(source="product.price",read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model=Order
        fields=['id','buyer','product','pname','category','description','pprice','quantity','totalprice']
```

In serializer we'll write fields that we want from referenced table explicitly and make it's read_only True so that it only views in get request.
Then we include it in fields so that we can fetch it in our api.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).